# Calculating the PDF of the monotonic function of a Random Variable results in error

Tags: density-function, function

I am given the PDF of a random variable X and I am asked to calculate the PDF of the random variable Y = g(X) = 1/X (Y's domain is the interval [0,1]).  By observing that g is monotonic I apply the formula that uses the inverse function.  However I end up with a negative PDF (see image).  Could you pinpoint the error? Your advice will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How did you get the pdf for X? What interval is X defined in?

Comment: The PDF of X is given.  X is defined over the interval [1, infinity)

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? It may require a self-study tag if that is the case.

Comment: Did you check to see if the density 3/$x^3$ integrates to 1.

Comment: I am studying Probabilities on my own as part of my professional development. It is indeed self-study. I am not sure I know what is a self-study tag.

Comment: You edit the post and type it in under the tag list.

Comment: You are misquoting the formula: you must take the *absolute value* of $dh/dy(y)$.  But don't ignore @Michael's comments: you contradict yourself by giving both $[0,1]$ and $[1,\infty)$ as its support and you will find that in neither case does this pdf integrate to $1$, as it must.